# set string size of gridview column in c#

Tags: c#, gridview, dataset, pageload

for example like I have 3 column in gridview. All the string length is more than 10 characters. I would like to fix the size of the 2nd column to 10. anyone have any idea how to do it?

can i do it in page load?

Comment: Do you *want* to do it in pageload, or are other events acceptable?

Comment: Additionally, have you tried anything yet? As it is, this is likely to be downvoted rather heavily. We don't write code for you, we assist with problems in your existing code

Answer (score 0):

Right click your Gridview, "Properties", "Columns", in "Selected Fields", choose your second column, "Style" then choose "ControlStyle" and set your width.

Comment: I am using customized gridview, not default one.

Comment: What does it mean customized gridview